# insert date to database using silverlight-enabled wcf service, visual basic

Tags: sql, vb.net, wcf, silverlight, sql-insert

I have difficulties in inserting record from silverlight interface to database using silverlight-enabled wcf service, visual basic. I followed a few tutorials in this topic, but somehow I couldn't finish my project in inserting data into database.

I followed VBRocks' blog on "Silverlight 3: Displaying SQL Server data " (http://garylima.blogspot.com/2009/09/silverlight-3-displaying-sql-server.html)to display data from database but failed to write record to the database.
I have 6 textboxes to receive user input, and I want to submit the information from the 6 boxes to the database.

Here is the Operationcontract in the register.svc.vb page:

```
<OperationContract()>
Public Sub InsertData(registerid As Integer, firstname As String, emailid As String, phoneno As String, loginname As String, password As String)

Dim db As New SilverlightDataContext()
Dim record As New Registration With {.registerID = registerid, .FirstName = firstname, .EmailID = emailid,
.PhoneNo = phoneno, .LoginName = loginname, .Password = password}
db.Registrations.InsertOnSubmit(record)
Try
db.SubmitChanges()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

Here are the subs in the Mainpage.xaml.vb, there is no error but no result too:

```
Private Sub SubmitRegister_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim mbservice As New RegisterClient()
Dim registerid = Convert.ToInt32(BoxRegisterID.Text)
mService.InsertDataAsync(registerid, BoxFirstName.Text, BoxEmailID.Text, BoxPhoneNo.Text, BoxLoginName.Text, BoxPassword.Text)
End Sub
```

Those are the main things in the project. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the code I have is right and I am able to insert a record into the database which I didn't notice by the time I posted this question. Hope this will help later.